# How do tell "swig -python -py3 myswig.i" not to include annotations

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, setuptools, swig

I need to use SWIG to support both Python 2.7 and Python 3.10.  [Yes, I know that Python 2.7 is dead, and we're doing our best to migrate users away from it as quickly as we can.]

I generate my module via `setuptools.setup` with a Swig extension. I can run the setup using both Python2 and Python3.  The `setuptools` program creates a separate shareable library for the Python2 and Python3 runs.  However both runs generate a `myswig.py` file in the same location.

It turns out that the Py2 and Py3 generated files are identical, except that the Py3 generated file contains annotations for the functions and the Py2 doesn't.  Python3 can read the Python2 generated file and works just fine.  Python2 cannot read the Python3 generated file.

I've tried both `%feature("autodoc", 0);` and leaving out this line completely, and I still get annotations.

So is there someway of either:

1. Turning off annotations in the generated file
2. Adding `from __future__ import annotations` automatically to the generated file

Comment: Another option maybe... If `setuptools` generates the `myswig.py` in the same location, build the Py3 one before Py2 so you are left with the one without annotations.  There are also `swig` options to change the output file's directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `-py3`. It's not required for Python 3, but enables Python 3-specific code features like annotations.

Comment: Hmm.  You're right, except. . . .  I need to generate slightly different _wrap code Python2 and Python3.  (Swig doesn't have any macro I can find that is simply "Is this a string" that is PyUnicode_Check on P3 and PyBytes_Check on P2.  Maybe I can use a different flat other than `is_swig_py3`.

Comment: @Frank Just like C, you can use -D to define a preprocessor macro and make decisions in the `swig.i` file about Py2/Py3 coding if needed.